# Pixelated text on website using google fonts

Tags: html, css, text

All of the text on a website I am working on is quite pixelated, which I'm trying to resolve. I'm using google fonts, and have linked it like so at the start of my CSS.
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');`

I'm also trying this on Chrome, if that changes anything.

I've already tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`, which hasn't worked, and saw something about a `filter:blur(0.56px)`, which i also tried and it didnt change anything. and don't know where to go from here.

I've attached a few examples of what it looks like now.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsqYT.png) ,
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/33RcK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your HTML and CSS, so we can't really tell what's wrong. But this snippet shows you how easy it ought to be, and it renders fine in my browser on my machine.

```css
body {font-family: Nunito;}
h1 {font-family: Oswald;}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```